# How can we measure RMSE in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, kalman-filter, mean-square-error, pykalman

I am doing an experiment using [Kalman Filters](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python/blob/master/10-Unscented-Kalman-Filter.ipynb). I have created a very small time series data ready with three columns formatted as follows. The full dataset is attached here for reproduciability since I can't attach a file on stackoverflow:

[csv file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/el1tkrdun0j2dk4/testdata.csv/file)

```
  time        X      Y
 0.040662  1.041667  1
 0.139757  1.760417  2
 0.144357  1.190104  1
 0.145341  1.047526  1
 0.145401  1.011882  1
 0.148465  1.002970  1
 ....      .....     .
```

I have read [the documetation](https://pykalman.github.io/#unscented-kalman-filter-user-s-guide) of the `Kalman Filter` and managed to do a simple linear prediction and here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from pykalman import KalmanFilter 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



df = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
print(df)
pd.set_option('use_inf_as_null', True)

df.dropna(inplace=True)


X = df.drop('Y', axis=1)
y = df['Y']



estimated_value= np.array(X)
real_value = np.array(y)

measurements = np.asarray(estimated_value)



kf = KalmanFilter(n_dim_obs=1, n_dim_state=1, 
                  transition_matrices=[1],
                  observation_matrices=[1],
                  initial_state_mean=measurements[0,1], 
                  initial_state_covariance=1,
                  observation_covariance=5,
                  transition_covariance=1)

state_means, state_covariances = kf.filter(measurements[:,1]) 
state_std = np.sqrt(state_covariances[:,0])
print (state_std)
print (state_means)
print (state_covariances)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.margins(x=0, y=0.05)

plt.plot(measurements[:,0], measurements[:,1], '-r', label='Real Value Input') 
plt.plot(measurements[:,0], state_means, '-b', label='Kalman-Filter') 
plt.legend(loc='best')
ax.set_xlabel("Time")
ax.set_ylabel("Value")
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot as an output

[image]

As we can see in the plot, the pattern seems to be captured reasonably well. How can we statistically measure the root-mean-square error (RMSE) (the error distance between the red and blue lines in the plot above)? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: to find RMSE between two lists `x` and `y` you can do `np.sqrt(np.mean((x-y)**2))`.

Comment: @TylerChen, that gives a `NaN` value sir.

Comment: are all of the entries in your arrays regular numbers, or are there some `inf` or `NaN`?

Comment: @TylerChen, yes they are regular numbers sir. I have included the small dataset with my post for reproduciability. It is only about 400 rows and it will not take you much time to re-run and check if it works for you. Thanks.

Comment: could you post the two arrays you want to find the RMSE of? I don't have `pykalman` installed.

Comment: Note `X` has three columns. Maybe you want to do it between `x=df['X']` and `y=df['Y']`? But in your plot it isn't this `y`.

Comment: In your plot the blue line is `x` but the red line is `state_means` which came from the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

mean_squared_error( measurements[:,1], state_means)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error.html) 0.22.0 you can pass `mean_squared_error()` the argument `squared=False` to return the RMSE.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
mean_squared_error(y_actual, y_predicted, squared=False)
```